# TensorFlow separable_conv2d slower than normal conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, gpu

I was trying to use `separable_conv2d` to build a small model that classify Cifar10 images, according to [MobileNets](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.04861) paper, it should be faster than traditional ConvNet, but it turns out that it is actually slower when the number of filters are small.

I test a model with only two `conv2d` and another model with one `conv2d` followed by one `separable_conv2d` with 32 filters each layer, and here is my results on one GTX1080ti:

```
training time for normal_conv after 2000 step: 8.18395892999979 sec
time for normal_conv after one forward step:  0.003980965999289765 sec
training time for sep_conv after 2000 step: 9.158266903999902 sec
time for sep_conv after one forward step:  0.0036441169995669043 sec
```

But when I increase number of filters to 128, the result is:

```
training time for normal_conv after 2000 step: 14.281644162001612 sec
time for normal_conv after one forward step:  0.007151683001211495 sec
training time for sep_conv after 2000 step: 13.0701530740007 sec
time for sep_conv after one forward step:  0.005937158999586245 sec
```

I am using tf 1.3, cuda8 and cudnn6, is the result normal??

Please help me clarify whether it is normal or I've done something wrong.

Here is my test code, just copy and paste and it should be running:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import timeit
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib.keras.python.keras.datasets.cifar10 import load_data

(x_train, y_train), (x_val, y_val) = load_data()
learning_rate = 0.001
num_steps = 1000
n_classes = 10
batch_size = 32

def reformat(labels):
    # Map 0 to [1.0, 0.0, 0.0 ...], 1 to [0.0, 1.0, 0.0 ...]
    labels = (np.arange(n_classes) == labels[:,None]).astype(np.float32)
    return  labels.reshape(labels.shape[0],10)
train_labels = reformat(y_train)
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 32, 32, 3])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])
weights1 = {}
weights2 = {}
dtype = tf.float32
with tf.name_scope('INIT_OP'):
    conv_initializer =  tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d(dtype=dtype)
    fc_initializer =  tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(dtype=dtype)

k = 3
kernel = 16

# Define weights for normal ConvNet
with tf.name_scope('VARIABLES_1'):
    weights1['conv1'] = tf.get_variable('conv1', [k, k, 3, kernel], initializer=conv_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights1['b1'] = tf.get_variable('b1', initializer=tf.zeros([kernel]))
    weights1['conv2'] = tf.get_variable('conv2', [k, k, kernel, kernel], initializer=conv_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights1['b2'] = tf.get_variable('b2', initializer=tf.zeros([kernel]))

    weights1['wd1'] = tf.get_variable('wd1', [8*8*kernel, 512], initializer=fc_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights1['bd1'] = tf.get_variable('bd1',  initializer=tf.zeros([512]) )
    weights1['wd2'] = tf.get_variable('wd2', [512, 10], initializer=fc_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights1['bd2'] = tf.get_variable('bd2',  initializer=tf.zeros([10]) )


#Define weights for separable ConvNet
with tf.name_scope('VARIABLES_sep'):
    weights2['conv1'] = tf.get_variable('2_conv1', [k, k, 3, kernel], initializer=conv_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights2['conv_dw2'] = tf.get_variable('conv_dw2', [k, k, kernel, 1], initializer=conv_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights2['conv_pw2'] = tf.get_variable('conv_pw2', [1, 1, kernel, kernel], initializer=conv_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)

    weights2['b1'] = tf.get_variable('2_b1', initializer=tf.zeros([kernel]))
    weights2['b2'] = tf.get_variable('2_b2', initializer=tf.zeros([kernel]))

    weights2['wd1'] = tf.get_variable('2_wd1', [8*8*kernel, 512], initializer=fc_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights2['bd1'] = tf.get_variable('2_bd1',  initializer=tf.zeros([512]) )
    weights2['wd2'] = tf.get_variable('2_wd2', [512, 10], initializer=fc_initializer, dtype=dtype, trainable=True)
    weights2['bd2'] = tf.get_variable('2_bd2',  initializer=tf.zeros([10]) )

def forward_conv_sep( inp, weights):

    hidden = conv_block(inp, weights2['conv1'], weights2['b1'])
    hidden = maxpool2d(hidden)
    hidden = conv_block_dw(hidden, weights2['conv_dw2'], weights2['conv_pw2'], weights2['b2'])
    hidden = maxpool2d(hidden)

    hidden = tf.reshape( hidden, [-1, np.prod([int(dim) for dim in hidden.get_shape()[1:]])] )
    fc1 = tf.matmul(hidden, weights2['wd1']) + weights2['bd1']
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)

    return tf.matmul(fc1, weights2['wd2']) + weights2['bd2']

def forward_conv( inp, weights):

    hidden = conv_block(inp, weights1['conv1'], weights1['b1'])
    hidden = maxpool2d(hidden)
    hidden = conv_block(hidden, weights1['conv2'], weights1['b2'])
    hidden = maxpool2d(hidden)

    hidden = tf.reshape( hidden, [-1, np.prod([int(dim) for dim in hidden.get_shape()[1:]])] )
    fc1 = tf.matmul(hidden, weights1['wd1']) + weights1['bd1']
    fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1)
    return tf.matmul(fc1, weights1['wd2']) + weights1['bd2']


def conv_block_dw(inp, cweight_w, cweight_p, bweight):
    no_stride =  [1,1,1,1]
    conv_output = tf.nn.separable_conv2d(inp, cweight_w, cweight_p, no_stride, 'SAME') + bweight
    return tf.nn.relu(conv_output)

def conv_block(inp, cweight, bweight, activation=tf.nn.relu):
    no_stride =  [1,1,1,1]
    conv_output = tf.nn.conv2d(inp, cweight, no_stride, 'SAME') + bweight
    return tf.nn.relu(conv_output)

def maxpool2d(inp, k=2):
    return tf.nn.max_pool(inp, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],
                          padding='SAME')

#logits for normal ConvNet
with tf.name_scope("forward_conv"):
    pred1 = forward_conv(x, weights1)

#Cost for normal ConvNet
with tf.name_scope("cost1"):
    loss1 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred1, labels=y)
    cost1 = tf.reduce_mean(loss1)

#training op for normal ConvNet
with tf.name_scope('train_op1'):
    train_op1 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost1)    

#logits for separable ConvNet
with tf.name_scope("forward_conv_sep"):
    pred2 = forward_conv_sep(x, weights2)

#Cost for separable ConvNet
with tf.name_scope("cost2"):
    loss2 = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred2, labels=y)
    cost2 = tf.reduce_mean(loss2)

# training op for separable ConvNet
with tf.name_scope('train_op2'):
    train_op2 = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost2)


with tf.name_scope('INIT'):
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(init)

    #train normal ConvNet for 2000 steps
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for step in range(num_steps):
        r = np.random.choice(y_train.shape[0], batch_size, replace=False)
        batch_data = x_train[r]
        batch_labels = train_labels[r]

        feed_dict = {x : batch_data, y: batch_labels}
        _ , l = sess.run([train_op1,cost1], feed_dict=feed_dict)

    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print ('training time for normal_conv after '+str(num_steps)+' step:',stop - start) 


    start = timeit.default_timer()
    feed_dict = {x : batch_data, y: batch_labels}
    predictions1 = sess.run(pred1, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print ('time for normal_conv after one forward step: ',stop - start)



    # train separable ConvNet for 2000 steps
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    for step in range(num_steps):
        r = np.random.choice(y_train.shape[0], batch_size, replace=False)
        batch_data = x_train[r]
        batch_labels = train_labels[r]

        feed_dict = {x : batch_data, y: batch_labels}
        _ , l = sess.run([train_op2,cost2], feed_dict=feed_dict)


    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print ('training time for sep_conv after '+str(num_steps)+' step:',stop - start) 

    start = timeit.default_timer()
    feed_dict = {x : batch_data, y: batch_labels}
    predictions = sess.run(pred2, feed_dict=feed_dict)
    stop = timeit.default_timer()
    print ('time for sep_conv after one forward step: ',stop - start)
```